How to restore database (daily) with multiple bak files using a T-SQL script?
I am trying to restore a database on a daily basis from multiple bak files that I get from a vendor.
I tried using GUI, and it worked.
I basically followed the same procedure as shared on the this link.
But, I need to do this on a daily basis with new BAK files that I receive.
I get these six bak files, and I would like to run a script to run once a day to refresh whole data in that database.

I tried something like on the bottom:
I got the script from this link:
USE Master; 
GO  
SET NOCOUNT ON 

-- 1 - Variable declaration 
DECLARE @dbName sysname
DECLARE @fileName sysname
DECLARE @standby sysname 
DECLARE @backupPath NVARCHAR(500) 
DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(500) 
DECLARE @fileList TABLE (backupFile NVARCHAR(255)) 
DECLARE @lastFullBackup NVARCHAR(500) 
DECLARE @lastDiffBackup NVARCHAR(500) 
DECLARE @backupFile NVARCHAR(500) 

-- 2 - Initialize variables 
SET @dbName = 'WH_BEE' 
SET @fileName = 'WH_BEE_' 
SET @backupPath = 'F:\NHFilesToday\' 
SET @standby = 'F:\backup\WH_BEE.bak' 

-- 3 - get list of files 
SET @cmd = 'DIR /b "' + @backupPath + '"'

INSERT INTO @fileList(backupFile) 
EXEC master.sys.xp_cmdshell @cmd 

-- 4 - Find latest diff backup 
---SELECT @lastDiffBackup = MAX(backupFile)  
---FROM @fileList  
---WHERE backupFile LIKE '%.DIF'  
   ---AND backupFile LIKE @dbName + '%' 
   ---AND backupFile > @lastFullBackup 

-- 5 - check for log backups 
DECLARE backupFiles CURSOR FOR  
   SELECT backupFile  
   FROM @fileList 
   WHERE backupFile LIKE '%.bak'  
   AND backupFile LIKE @fileName + '%' 

OPEN backupFiles  

-- Loop through all the files for the database  
FETCH NEXT FROM backupFiles INTO @backupFile  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
   SET @cmd = 'RESTORE LOG [' + @dbName + '] FROM DISK = '''  
       + @backupPath + @backupFile + ''' WITH STANDBY='''+ @standby +'''' 
   
   FETCH NEXT FROM backupFiles INTO @backupFile  

EXEC (@cmd)
END 

CLOSE backupFiles  
DEALLOCATE backupFiles  

-- 6 - put database in a useable state 
SET @cmd = 'RESTORE DATABASE [' + @dbName + '] WITH RECOVERY' 
PRINT @cmd

I got this error:

I am not sure these bak files are considered log backup files or something else..
Do I have to delete database and restore database?
I need some help with fixing the script or is there any simpler script I could use?
Update (8/18/2024):
I got this error after I tried the replaced part 5 (leaving all other parts (1,2,3 & 6) same from the original).

This is what the original db looks like (normal status):

This is where mdf and ldf files are located:

I am not sure where the standby file is/should be located:
I just created this line (without actually this file exists).
I am not sure what to do with this line of the script.
SET @standby = 'F:\backup\WH_BEE.bak' 

Update (8/19/2024):
This is generated script:
USE [master]
RESTORE DATABASE [WH_BEE] FROM  
DISK = N'F:\NH\WH_BEE_20240819_1.bak',  
DISK = N'F:\NH\WH_BEE_20240819_2.bak',  
DISK = N'F:\NH\WH_BEE_20240819_3.bak',  
DISK = N'F:\NH\WH_BEE_20240819_4.bak',  
DISK = N'F:\NH\WH_BEE_20240819_5.bak', 
DISK = N'F:\NH\WH_BEE_20240819_6.bak' WITH  FILE = 1, 
MOVE N'WH_Data1' TO N'F:\data\WH_BEE.MDF',  
MOVE N'WH_Data2' TO N'F:\data\WH_BEE_1.NDF',  
MOVE N'WH_Log' TO N'G:\log\WH_BEE.LDF',  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 5

GO


see if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18360666/seeking-to-restore-from-multiple-bak-files-to-a-test-sql-database

"I tried using GUI, and it worked." FYI: If you can prepare the desired action in SSMS, instead of executing it by clicking OK, you can often ask SSMS to script the action for you. Then tweak the generated T-SQL script as necessary. https://imgur.com/a/CrQehhD

@Yano_of_Queenscastle Thank you so much. I have a question. How do I modify the area where it has a static date like "20240819_1.bak" to wildcard kinda like "..2024*_1_bak'? I updated the post with the script that I have. (on the top)

@Java what kind of backup generated those files: FULL, DIFF or LOG backup? In the original script you were treating them as if they were log backups, now, from the generated script of update (8/19/2024) it seems you're restoring from a full backup. Do you still have an error?

@Ronaldo I guess they are full back up. Sorry. I am still trying to learn this stuff. Sorry that I confused you. I actually gave up on my previous T-SQL and posted to a new thread (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78890056/how-to-concatenate-t-sql-script-with-a-wildcard-and-to-be-more-dynamic) using the generated T-SQL. Thank you.

Your problem seems to be that you're treating each file as if it was a new backup when they're actually all pieces of only one backup file. Your final command should look something like this:
RESTORE LOG [WH_BEE] FROM 
DISK = 'F:\NHFilesToday\WH_BEE_1.bak',
DISK = 'F:\NHFilesToday\WH_BEE_2.bak',
DISK = 'F:\NHFilesToday\WH_BEE_3.bak',
DISK = 'F:\NHFilesToday\WH_BEE_4.bak',
DISK = 'F:\NHFilesToday\WH_BEE_5.bak'
WITH STANDBY = 'F:\backup\WH_BEE.bak'

To achieve it, you can replace your step 5 for this:
-- 5 - check for log backups 
DECLARE backupFiles CURSOR FOR  
   SELECT backupFile  
   FROM @fileList 
   WHERE backupFile LIKE '%.bak'  
   AND backupFile LIKE @fileName + '%' 

OPEN backupFiles  

-- Loop through all the files for the database  
FETCH NEXT FROM backupFiles INTO @backupFile  

SET @cmd = 'RESTORE LOG [' + @dbName + '] FROM ' + CHAR(13) 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  

    SET @cmd = @cmd + 'DISK = ''' + @backupPath + @backupFile + ''',' + CHAR(13)
    FETCH NEXT FROM backupFiles INTO @backupFile

END

SET @cmd = SUBSTRING(@cmd,1,LEN(@cmd)-2) + CHAR(13) + 'WITH STANDBY = '''+ @standby + ''''
EXEC (@cmd)

CLOSE backupFiles  
DEALLOCATE backupFiles


Thank you for your help. I replaced the Part 5 with your code and got the error on the top (Update on the original post). Does Part 6 look ok (stay same)? Also, the original DB is on "normal" status.

@Java, your new error seems to imply that you're trying to restore a backup from a database that was created on an older (or maybe not patched) version of SQL Server to a newer one. If that's the case, it might be a limitation of the option WITH STANDBY and the correction would be just remove that option of the restore command. Please, run a SELECT @@VERSION on both servers to compare if the server your're restoring has a newer version of SQL Server.

@Java see This backup cannot be restored using WITH STANDBY because a database upgrade is needed. Reissue the RESTORE without WITH STANDBY
